# Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при пустом значении, поле не выводилось.

Tags: php

Есть кусок кода. Вот такой.

```
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $text_location; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Данный кусок таблицы выводит поле производитель, причём выводит его вне зависимости заполнено оно или нет. Необходимо условие при котором если поле не заполнено, то выводится не будет. 
Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
    <?php if ($location = not NULL) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $text_location; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Но так поле вообще не выводится. Прошу помощи. Знания в Языке ПхП слабоватые. Только учусь...

Comment: @KeH192, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо вашего куска вставьте:

```
<?php if (!empty($text_location) && !empty($location)) echo "<tr><td>$text_location</td><td>$location</td></tr>"; ?>
```

Comment: && - исправьте

Comment: Человек только учиться, смешивание php-кода и html-разметки - плохая привычка.

Comment: Андрей, можно вкратце чем запись: <b><?php echo $my_bold; ?></b> лучше <?php echo "<b>$my_bold</b>"; ?> или скажем <?php echo '<b>',$my_bold,'</b>'; ?>

Comment: В данном конкретном случае - ничем. А вот в большом куске спагетти php/html кода резко снижает понимание происходящего и возможность дальнейшей "переделки".

Comment: @Андрей Толмачевский не по теме вопроса, но. Зачем нужно было городить php (смесь html и кода), чтобы теперь объявлять это неправильным? Ведь был же perl, в котором мухи (html) и котлеты (perl) были отдельно. Мне просто интересно...

Comment: Возможно меня не правильно поняли. Я призывал к разделению логики и отображения. @alexlz, php изначально задумывался как шаблонизатор, на сегодняшний день он уже нечто большее.

Comment: @Андрей Толмачевский да простят модераторы, но. Я не знаю, кто такой "шаблонизатор" (как в х/ф "Осенний марафон" -- "Я узнал много новых слов"), но прожект стал уже совсем не тем, чем задумывался, уже перерос все разумные пределы, и неизвестно сколько времени это ещё продлится. Надеюсь, что не очень долго. Но пока пипл хавает.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно проверить именно на null, то вот так

```
<?php if (isset($text_location, $text)): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $text_location; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Если на **непустоту**, то вот так (если $text_location && $text определены)

```
<?php if ($text_location && $text): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $text_location; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

А если могут оказаться не определены, то нужно смешать первый и второй вариант вот так:

```
<?php if (isset($text_location, $text) && $text_location && $text): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $text_location; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: а я вот не люблю `if () : endif;`  и на то есть причина - vim не видит это как блок в отличии от if () {}, кроме того вообще непонятно какой смысл в том чтобы писать больше.

Comment: Вопрос вкуса, я предпочитаю в  шаблонах использовать endif, endforeach и т.д. Это избавляет от некоторый "неопределенности" закрывающей скобки и делает код более читабельным.

Comment: @eicto Это скорее Ваши проблемы. Если такого нет в matchit.vim, то добавить несложно.